# Oracle HTTP server (OHS) and SSL

Tags: linux, oracle, ssl, oracle-apex

Здравствуйте

Мне нужно обновить сертификаты в бразуере для корректной работы с APEX

1) Оракл - Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition 11.2.0.3.0, сервер на линуксе.

2) С помощью openssl я создал ewallet.p12 файл (из новых присланных мне сертификатов и закрытого ключа) и расположил его в определенной папке (давайте назовем путь к этой папке - wallet_path). При этом команда по созданию ewallet заставила ввести пароль для защиты закрытого ключа.

3) С помощью OWM я нашел путь к ewallet.p12, установил auto-login и появился файл cwallet.cco.

4) Затем в opmn.xml поменял путь:

```
   ssl enabled="true" wallet-file="...old_path..."/
```

на путь к кошельку wallet_path

5) Потом в строке с текстом

SSLWallet ...

файла SSL.conf прописал опять путь к кошельку

После всех действий когда я пытаюсь стартануть или перезагрузить opmn с помощью opmnctl он не стартует, а в логе opmn.log :

```
[ERROR:1] [] [ons-secure] Failed to open wallet (file:..<путь wallet_path>..) [default password] (29106)
```

and

в ohs логе:

```
[ERROR:32] ... Cannot open an encrypted wallet file:..<путь wallet_path>.. while process is managed by OPMN. Enable it as SSO wallet
```

Вроде алгоритм стандартный для создания кошелька и перезагрузки opmn, где нужно фиксить?